# How to store and fetch data systematically with using SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

I have an app for listing movies. User should be able to list their favorite movies in the feed. I am doing that with using SharedPreferences. For list I am using ListView. However when I add new movie in list, it replaces with previous one.

This is ListActivity ,

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    ImageView listTitleImage;
    ImageView homeIcon;
    ImageView userListIcon;
    ImageView searchIcon;
    ImageView accountIcon;

    public static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listTitleImage = findViewById(R.id.listTitleImage);
        homeIcon = findViewById(R.id.homeListImageViewList);
        userListIcon = findViewById(R.id.homeListImageViewList);
        searchIcon = findViewById(R.id.searchImageViewList);
        accountIcon = findViewById(R.id.accountImageViewList);

        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Save", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String title = sharedPreferences.getString(String.valueOf(1),"No movie");
        String poster = sharedPreferences.getString(String.valueOf(2),"No poster");

        ArrayList<List> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new List(title,poster));

        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this,R.layout.movie_list,list);

        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }
}
```

And this is where I store movie details.  'resultList' is the arraylist which I am using for getting data from api.

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {


        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menuAdd){

            String title = resultList.get(pos).getTitle();
            String posterpath = resultList.get(pos).getPoster_path();

            sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Save", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(String.valueOf(1),title);
            editor.putString(String.valueOf(2),posterpath);
            editor.apply();

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,ListActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent1);

            return true;

        }
        else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menuShowDetails){

            int movieId = resultList.get(pos).getMovieId();
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MovieDetails.class);
            intent1.putExtra("movie_id",movieId);
            context.startActivity(intent1);
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: the problem is that, when you "add" the values (`editor.putString(String.valueOf(1),title);`and  `editor.putString(String.valueOf(2),posterpath);`) what you are doing is to override the previous values. You might be looking for `putStringSet` or even use SQLITE database instead

Comment: Use a local database at least mate, it's way easier to use a list that way, also use a recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

the best solution is that you have to use SQLite database or room database for storing a list because it's easy to use and update every time if you want to update...

For Sqlite reference - https://www.javatpoint.com/android-sqlite-tutorial

for Room Database Reference - https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-android-jetpack-675a89a0e942